# Proving the CCA-insecurity of El Gamal encryption scheme

Tags: elgamal-encryption, chosen-ciphertext-attack

I am trying to prove that El Gamal Encryption is not CCA-Secure.

If an adversary queried the encryption oracle for the encryption of $m=1$, he'll get a pair $(c_1,c_2)=(g^y,g^{xy}\cdot m)=(g^y,g^{xy}\cdot 1)=(g^y,g^{xy}).$ Then he could calculate $g^{-xy}$. Then he sends the challenger a pair $(m_0,m_1)$. When he gets the challenge ciphertext $(c_1^*,c_2^*)$ he can decrypt it and finds out which message has been encrypted. Hence, the adversary wins the experiment with non-negligible probability.

Does this prove make sense, or did I miss something?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

This solution does not work since the value of y does not belong to the key, but it's generated randomly for every encryption.

A right **solution** would be as follows:

The adversary chooses some messages $m_0=x\ and\ m_1=y$. Then he sends these two messages $(m_0,m_1)$ to the challenger and get the encryption of one of them $<c_1,c_2>$. Then he picks some z and multiplies it with the  $c_2$ so he gets a new ciphertext $<c_1, c_2 . z> $. Then he queries the decryption oracle for the decryption of the new ciphertext. So, the resulting plaintext is either $x . z$ or $y . z$. Hence he can know which message has been encrypted.

Comment: Welocme to Cryto.SE! Your proof doesn't quite work or at least it proves something else ;). Keep in mind that in ElGamal, $y$ is sampled at random for every new message. so after you ask for encryption of $1$, the next encryption will be $(g^{y'}, g^{xy'}*m)$. So as you've shown ElGamal would be insecure if we reused $y$.

Comment: Now on the question of proving IND-CCA (in)security, in the challenge phase you'll submit $(m_0, m_1)$ and receive $E(m_b), b \in \{0,1\}$. The idea is to used the decryption oracle to get the decryption of some crafted ciphertext $c'$ and use that to decide whether $b = 0$ or $b = 1$. Obviously $c'$ can be $E(m_b)$ , so the challenge is how can we make up a valid ciphertext?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in the CCA-security experiment for public key encryption schemes in "Introduction to modern cryptography", (sk,pk) <-- $Gen(1^{n})$ is called once at the begin of the experiment. and then the generated key will be used to encrypt and decrypt all messages in the experiment without picking a new y every time.That was the confusion :(.

Comment: The $key-gen$ algorithm is called once for sure but that algorithm generates $(x, g^x)$, where $x$ is the private key and $g^x$ the public key.But for encryption you still need to generate a new $y$ for encryption otherwise ElGamal would be completely insecure. In that case there's no point to really study CCA security since everyone could decrypt any ciphertext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as written, your technique doesn't work (as there's no specific reason why the encryption oracle use the same $y$ as the challenge ciphertext).

You need a different approach.  For one, the adversary doesn't need to depend on an encryption oracle; if he has the public key, then he can encrypt anything he wants.  What he does need to do is use the *decryption oracle* (as that performs an operation that the adversary cannot do himself).

So, how can the adversary create a ciphertext which is not the same as the challenge ciphertext, but when submitted to the decryption oracle, would tell him the answer?

Comment: He can multiply the challenge ciphertext  with some value $x$. Then he can query the decryption oracle for the decryption of $c.x$ since this value has not been queried yet. I think I got it! thank you :)

Comment: @OmarRenawi: By George, I think you've got it!  In fact, that is precisely the answer (with x fixed at 2) I wrote before I decided that having you figure out the answer would be a better lesson...